# Cloud logging service or WP7 logging practice

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, logging, cloud

Is there free, usable service for logging to the cloud? Is there .NET clients for it? 
Or what is the best way to log on WP7 application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free service for logging some data, including exceptions and custom log-events. Just take a look at http://www.mtiks.com

I'm quite pleased with it right now.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, but I stumble to some bugs in this service. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would be the easiest to implement what you are looking for use azure and the azure toolkit for wp7 http://watwp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think it would be very useful tool in future